# Is there any website for a detail chronological description of U.S. index futures market development?

Tags: futures

Is there any website for a detail chronological description of U.S. index futures market development? I have searched online for some time but unable to locate particular focus on index futures market development... A lot of them regard the general futures market as a whole... 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't know of one. This exchange brochure says the S&P Index Futures, the first one to be traded, was introduced in 1982. https://www.cmegroup.com/education/files/understanding-stock-index-futures.pdf At the time it was a major innovation and most futures were for agricultural commodities or metals. Index futures trading grew quickly after that and was blamed by many for the Nov 1987 crash, prompting a govt investigation and review that is available in book form and probably contains other historical details if you are interested (the brady commission report 1988).

Answer (score 1):

You could probably figure some things out by getting historical trade price and volume data for the most important contracts. I suspect that much of it would be available from the exchange websites.

Also, you could try the exchanges themselves. They are large organisations, and they might have in-house archival teams.